# Why do we need HMAC?

Tags: hash, tls, hmac, certificates

AFAIK, HMAC solves the collision problem of hash algorithms by mixing in a pre shared secret.

Can't we just use the pre shared secret to symmetrically encrypt data and leave out the hashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HMAC solves the collision problem of hash algorithms by mixing in a pre shared secret.

No, HMAC is a construction of a *message authentication code* based on a hash function. Specifically intended to be used with hash functions based on the Merkle-Damgård construction.

> Can't we just use the pre shared secret to symmetrically encrypt data and leave out the hashing?

The premise of the question is wrong, so the question makes no sense. A message authentication code provides *authenticity*. I.e., the receiver can be certain that the message was not tampered with in transit. It does not, and does not aim to, provide *confidentiality*.